# Escape special character in terminal but not in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In terminal, we should use escape character for this command

```
echo "Hello\!"
```

But in script, we don't need to use escape character for last command.
Actually to produce same output, we can't use escape character.
Why is there a difference between terminal and script?

Comment: Scripts don't have a history, so why should history operations be allowed?

Comment: @xxfelixxx you need if using quote

Comment: You can just use single quotes and avoid the history substitution. `echo 'Hello!'`

Comment: @xxfelixxx Didn't notice that is a history substitution at first. So if i write this command to a .sh file, it is not treated as a history substitution?

Comment: Yes, it will work the same.

Comment: @xxfelixxx but i don't need to use escape character for same command in .sh file, and it will print Hello!

Comment: You can turn off history substitution in the shell if you want to have identical behavior in both.

Comment: `set +H` disables history substitution in the interactive shell.

Comment: @xxfelixxx why there are different behaviours? That is my intention to ask this question

Comment: Because when running commands from the interactive terminal, it is handy to be able to use history substitution.  A consequence of this is that now the `!` character has to be treated differently.

Comment: @michael, it's different because history expansion is an extension for interactive use only, and is off by default in noninteractive shells.

Comment: @xxfelixxx not get what you mean. What seems to me is in terminal ! is treated as history substitution, but in script ! is not treated as that, not sure why there is difference here

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah, this makes sense to me, thx

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Interactive vs Script bash are different environments.  Have a read of `man bash` for details.